# add and remove controls on HTML5 audio player

Tags: html, audio

How do I add and remove specific controls on an HTML5 audio player?  I'd like to remove the volume control, time display, and the progress bar.  I'm using the following code to show the player.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="http://example.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"> 
Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio> 

<style>
audio { width: 10%; display: block;}
</style>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't mix and match native controls. You either have all the native controls or you have no native controls.

If you want some controls, then you'll need to reproduce them using the JavaScript APIs and DOM.

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose that's why I couldn't find any examples on how to do it.  I looked up JavaScript APIs and DOM and it seems like that is going to take a lot of figuring out.  Basically, I want to display only the play button.  Do you happen to have any suggestions on how to do this?  Or, maybe you could point me to a tutorial or something.

Comment: I appreciate the link, but I didn't really understand it enough to make just a play button.  Oh well, I'll keep searching.