# Customizing the Audio Tag in HTML5

Tags: html, html5-audio

The following code snippet

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

generates the following audio controls:

[image]

**Question 1:** Is there a way to remove the progress bar portion of these audio controls, such that the only thing visible is the play/pause button and the volume knob?

**Question 2:** Is there a way to totally customize the appearance of the play button using another image?

Comment: Your question 1 is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052426/add-and-remove-controls-on-html5-audio-player And number 2 is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095544/how-to-change-play-button-images-in-html5-audio

Answer (score 1):

With MediaElement.js http://mediaelementjs.com/#api you can customize your html5 audio control easily. Live demo with the code http://designshack.net/articles/css/custom-html5-audio-element-ui/